# Trying to access innerHTML of div in <Script> but it results in undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I'm using masterpage for header for all content pages, and in one of the content pages I'm trying to get the innerHTML of a div to input control(that is in the same page) so I can access the updated innerHTML from code behind. 
So on button click this is what I have for the script.

```
 var myDivObj = $('#<%=txt.ClientID %>'); // div
   if (myDivObj) {
   var myInputObj = $('#<%=hdnDivContents.ClientID %>'); //input
   myInputObj.val(myDivObj.innerHTML); //assigns div's innerHTML to the input control 
   }
```

//However, during break, myDivObj.innerHTML hints that it is Undefined.

Comment: `if (myDivObj)` will always be true, use  `if (myDivObj.length)` to detect the presence of the div as opposed to an empty jQuery collection object (all objects are truthy).

Comment: innerHtml in jquery is taken using html() function http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: I just tried it but it still returns true.

Comment: @user3358347 - I put it to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` works for "native" `Javascript` objects. As you're using a `jQuery` selector you should use the `.html()` method.

```
myInputObj.val(myDivObj.html());
```

Also, you didn't mention it, but to check the existence of an element (or many of them) when using a `jQuery` selector, you should use the `.length` property. Otherwise your condition will always pass as `true`.

```
if (myDivObj.length) {
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/jvk4f16c/1/)

Comment: Upvote for being the first one to spot the problem. All the other answers say the same. I've just edited it a bit, if you don't mind.

Comment: @dandavis Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: This is always jquery object - check myDivObj.length > 0

Comment: I see. I got blinded somehow. @fly_ua, you should fix your answer then, although the OP didn't refer to this as a problem.

Comment: the length conditional bug is not as noticiable; it will just update too often instead of exploding

Answer (score 0):

It looks like myDivObj is a jQuery object - referring to the element with id <%=txt.ClientID %>,
but `.innerHTML` is a javascript function, which will fail if you use it on a jQuery object.

Try writing this

```
myInputObj.val(myDivObj.get(0).innerHTML);
```

And also, the if check `if(myDivObj)` will always satisfy, as myDivObj will be a jQuery object either of the element with id <%=txt.ClientID %> or of null, but the object will always be present.
You should write the if check as `if(myDivObj.length)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `html()`

```
var myDivObj = $('#<%=txt.ClientID %>'); // div
   if (myDivObj) {
   var myInputObj = $('#<%=hdnDivContents.ClientID %>'); //input
   myInputObj.val(myDivObj.html()); //assigns div's innerHTML to the input control 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function `$` returns a jQuery object rather than the element itself. To look up an element by id, which offers direct access to the `.innerHTML` property, then skip jQuery like this:

```
var myDivObj = document.getElementById('<%=txt.ClientID %>');
if (myDivObj) {
    var myInputObj = document.getElementById('<%=hdnDivContents.ClientID %>');
    myInputObj.value = myDivObj.innerHTML; // assigns div's innerHTML to the input control 
}
```